# gnome extension to search for active window

Tags: gnome, extension

I've already viewed this one [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1001/window-search-provider/), and it doesn't appear to be the one I'm searching for. Back a while ago, I had stumbled upon a gnome extension that looked alike apple's spotlight search , yet it claimed to search for active window that were currently opened.

Unfortunately, I didn't install it then, and I'm desparately in need of that extension, and I was wondering if the community would be familiar with it. Please drop the link/name of the extension if you've been using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be referring to an extension like [Switcher by dlandau](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/973/switcher/). This extension brings up a compact search box. It is around for a while and still actively updated.

Comment: yes, yes, yes, bingo!!!! thanks a tonne

Comment: I thought it was working as expected previously. Do you know how it can be configured to result only active windows? It seems to be launching apps instead

Comment: According to the description on the website, the app is designed to show launchable apps too. Not sure whether it can be configured otherwise without editing the source code.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME extension `Alt-Tab Active Windows`

[image]

It works by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Tab</kbd> which shows a graphic of active windows in the centre of the screen.

Other similar GNOME extensions:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, since it hasn't any screenshots, and it was on as far as I remember gnome's official extension site, but, I so regret I didn't install it when I had found it. It's interface was similar to apple's spotlight search

Answer (score 0):

### Window Search Provider (by klorenz)

This GNOME Shell extension will let you search for currenly windows using GNOME's search feature (press <kbd>super</kbd> or click *Activities* in the top left corner).

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1001/window-search-provider/

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support the more recent versions of GNOME.